# TypeError on any artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel

- Laravel Version: 7.23.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.8
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL v8.0.21

This morning I upgraded Laravel to version 7.23.0 due to the current  vulnerability (https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-cookie-security-releases). But now I get the following error message with every Artisan Command:

```php
php artisan package:discover --ansi

   TypeError 

  Illuminate\Container\Container::bind(): Argument #2 ($concrete) must be of type Closure|string|null

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:238
    234|         // bound into this container to the abstract type and we will just wrap it
    235|         // up inside its own Closure to give us more convenience when extending.
    236|         if (! $concrete instanceof Closure) {
    237|             if (! is_string($concrete)) {
  > 238|                 throw new \TypeError(self::class.'::bind(): Argument #2 ($concrete) must be of type Closure|string|null');
    239|             }
    240| 
    241|             $concrete = $this->getClosure($abstract, $concrete);
    242|         }

      +11 vendor frames 
  12  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider))

      +5 vendor frames 
  18  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Since I think this would be a more noticeable bug, and I haven't found an issue on GitHub, I didn't open a new one and ask for help here :)

However, I don't really have any idea what exactly might be causing the problem.

Comment: you may check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33539
I think you also need to show the full stack trace and you also need to make sure of your facade/ignition version

Comment: Try to delete `bootstrap/cache/` files and tehn composer update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Abdel-aziz hassan for the link (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33539).

I found out that facade/ignition was on an old version. I updated it and now it works.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `instance` instead of `bind` helps me.

```
$app->instance(Service::class, $serviceInstance)
```

instead

```
$app->bind(Service::class, $serviceInstance)
```